My guitar is plugged in but isn’t making any noise
I currently am having issues with my epiphone Ebony explorer. I plugged it in one day and it just stopped working. Only loud buzzing/ humming occurs. It’s not my cable and it’s not my amp. ( I’ve had the same set up with my other guitars and they work perfectly fine. I’ve opened it up and all the connections seem fine. I’m assuming it’s a problem with my pickups but the connection seems alright. Anyone know what may have happened ? (It’s also not my input)

Without the guitar and a multimeter at hand, very hard to tell...

Sounds like you broke it :(

The duplicate provided is not a good fit for this question as it talks mostly about active guitars and explorers are typically passive. To me this sounds like a wiring issue  inside the guitar or maybe a cold solder joint.

@JohnBelzaguy I think the duplicate is a good fit.  That question is not about active guitars, that is just a possibility the sole answerer decided to address.  You could write a second answer that covers other issues a passive guitar may have.
